# soupstrainer and php can't see all divs found

Tags: php, python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to fill a form with python, then retrieve the resulting page to use it in my .php file. Python code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import SoupStrainer, BeautifulSoup 
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()


def sitecheck(SITE_URL2):
    URL2 = "https://achecker.ca/checker/index.php"
    payload = {
        'uri': SITE_URL2,
        'enable_html_validation': 'on',
        'enable_css_validation': 'on',
        'show_source': 'on',
        'radio_gid[]': '3'
    }
    payload = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload).encode("utf-8")

    # prepare the option for the chrome driver and start chrome driver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = True    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(URL2)
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("checkuri")
    inputElement.send_keys(SITE_URL2)

    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Options").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("enable_html_validation").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("enable_css_validation").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("radio_gid_3").click()
    driver.find_element_by_name("validate_uri").click()

    html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
    driver.quit()

    s = ""
    fonly = SoupStrainer('div', {
        'id': ['AC_errors', 'AC_likely_problems', 'AC_potential_problems', 'AC_html_validation_result',
               'AC_css_validation_result']})
    for link in BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml", parse_only=fonly):
        s = s + str(link)

    print(s)
    return ;
```

while .php code is this:

```
<?php
$path="pyt"; 
        chdir($path); 

        $output = shell_exec('python newfile_1.py');
        "<pre>$output</pre>"        
?>
```

Now, the result in python works well, I can see all the selected divs. But when I call it with php, I'm able to see only three of these, it look like "AC_html_validation_result" and "AC_css_validation_result" don't exist anymore. 
**MY QUESTION**: I would like to have the same result in my .php file and in my .py file, I have no idea why this is not working. The thing I need is to fill the form and get the divs in the resulting page to copy them in a php file. Also, I noticed that this code is very slow and I'm wondering why.